# toggle background color of selected list item react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

what i want to do it when i click on one of the list items i want the class selected to be applied and when i click again i want it to be removed, so basically a toggle function, but it happens to all 3 list items, so if i click on one, all get selected, but i want it so only one can be selected at a time

```
import React from 'react';



export default class Order extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      selected: false,
    };
  }

 toggleChoice() {
    const selected = !this.state.selected;
    this.setState({selected});
  }
  render() {
    const { selected } = this.state;
    const selectedCircle = selected ? " selected":"";
    return (
        <div class="container" id="order-layout">
            <div class="row">

                    <div class="card-panel white">
                      <div class="center">
                        <h5>Your Order</h5>
                        <p class="margin-top-30 bold">Choose Pizza size in cm</p>
                        <ul class="margin-top-30">
                            <li ><div onClick={this.toggleChoice.bind(this)} class={"circle-20 hovered-circle" + selectedCircle}>20</div></li>
                            <li ><div onClick={this.toggleChoice.bind(this)} class={"circle-30 hovered-circle" + selectedCircle}>30</div></li>
                            <li ><div onClick={this.toggleChoice.bind(this)} class={"circle-40 hovered-circle" + selectedCircle}>40</div></li>
                        </ul> 

                      </div>
                    </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `selectedCircle` has the same value for all list items. If you click on one of list items `selectedCircle` changes for the other ones too.

Thus, you need for every list item the different piece of state.

You can try something like this :

First change your state to :

```
this.state = {
  selectedCircle: {},
};
```

Your toggleChoice function needs to know on which list item you clicked. You can change it to something like this :

```
toggleChoice(name, event) {
   let selected = this.state.selectedCircle;
   selected = {};
   let selectedCircles = selected[name] == "selected" ? "" : "selected";
   selected[name] = selectedCircles;
   this.setState({selectedCircle: selected});
}
```

Then in your render you need to add to every list item the appropriate piece of state. Change your render function to something like :

```
render() {

return (
    <div className="container" id="order-layout">
        <div className="row">

                <div className="card-panel white">
                  <div className="center">
                    <h5>Your Order</h5>
                    <p className="margin-top-30 bold">Choose Pizza size in cm</p>
                    <ul className="margin-top-30">
                        <li ><div onClick={this.toggleChoice.bind(this, "first")} className={"circle-20 hovered-circle " + this.state.selectedCircle["first"]}>20</div></li>
                        <li ><div onClick={this.toggleChoice.bind(this, "second")} className={"circle-30 hovered-circle " + this.state.selectedCircle["second"]}>30</div></li>
                        <li ><div onClick={this.toggleChoice.bind(this, "third")} className={"circle-40 hovered-circle " + this.state.selectedCircle["third"]}>40</div></li>
                    </ul> 

                  </div>
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
);
```

And voilà, that should work. Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1160/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i understand now, however still with this you can choose all 3 at the same time, and what i want is to just be able to choose 1 option and not the others

Comment: @user3209048 you just need to clear your state in toggleChoice function `selected = {}` . See updated fiddle and question.

Comment: @Boky works like a charm, thank you very much! seems like ive been having a really bad mind block :D, i have just started learning react 3 days ago, finished the course on codecademy and now just trying to do some random SPA to practice it, but i am getting stuck with stuff like these, i guess ill grasp the logic more as  long as i practice more, thanks again!